# When creating a Drupal 7 content type programmatically, is there a way to add tuples of fields?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

In Drupal 7, I'd like to create a Person content type. A person may have multiple profiles - an administrator should be able to select which profile will be considered the primary one. So, that means that I need a tuple consisting of:

A textarea, for the profile text
A checkbox, indicating that this is the primary profile
A textbox, for naming this particular profile

I need functionality to behave like that of any of the lists: I can click "Add another Item", and a set of all three of these fields will appear.

I have a vague idea of how this can be executed, but it involves using the form API to add fields before the form renders each time, as well as the necessary AJAX behavior. This seems a bit overcomplicated, since this would also necessitate creating an additional DB table to hold these tacked-on fields.

Is there a relatively simple way of doing this solely through `hook_install()`?

Comment: Have you tried the [Field Collection module](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use drupal.org/project/profile2 or you can complete it using standard Drupal functionality, i.e. create a content type named, let's say, 'myprofile' and add all the fields use need. Then add a nodereferece (http://drupal.org/project/references) field to the user standard profie that would point to your 'myprofile' content type.
So all the 'myprofile' content, created by that user would be his profiles and the one pointed in his standard profile will be his default.
I hope it's clear enough )